# C - prevent interrupt activiation - MSP430

Tags: c, microcontroller, interrupt, msp430

I wrote the following code to initialize the buttons on my MSP430 microcontroller:

```
    void Initialize(void){

       P1REN |= 0x02;                          
       P1OUT |= 0x02;                         
       P2REN |= 0x02;                          
       P2OUT |= 0x02;                          
       P1IE |= 0x02;                           
       P2IE |= 0x02;                              
       P1IFG &= ~0x02;                         
       P2IFG &= ~0x02;                         

       TA1CTL = TASSEL_1+ID_0+MC_2+TACLR;      
       TA1R = 40000;                         

       _BIS_SR(GIE);                           

    }
```

How do I prevent that the line P1IFG &= ~0x02; provokes an Interrupt? I'm new to microcontroller programming and read that this line provokes an interrupt if something changes in the P1IE register.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You can't disable interrupts from user space.

Comment: First clear the flag (the `P1IFG` line), then enable the interrupts with (the `P1IE` line).

Comment: @NiVeR There is no user space on an MSP430.

Comment: thanks changing P1IFG and P1IE did it for me !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The User's Guide says:

> Writing to P1OUT, P1DIR, P2OUT, or P2DIR can result in setting the corresponding P1IFG or P2IFG flags.

However, this code clears the PxIFG flags before enabling the interrupts globally (GIE), so an unintentional interrupt cannot happen.

Comment: Thanks for sour answer ! I went through the Code with the debugger and sometimes the port 2 interrupt is called after the P1IFG line that's the reason why I'm asking

Comment: "Sometimes" sounds like an hardware issue, i.e., there was a change at the pin. But that would have to be solved [elsewhere](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/).